# TweenMax.to() is jumpy/not smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap

I'm trying to make a web-based like slide show and am trying to figure out the best way to transition between slides.
 I initially used jQuery `Animate()`, but found it to be not smooth at all. I came across the GreenSock TweenLite/TweenMax library and have seen improvement. 
Unfortunately, things still aren't the smoothest. 
This is what I have thus far:

http://codepen.io/FluidOfInsanity/pen/PbJbWm

It runs pretty good in Firefox, but struggles in Chrome quite a bit. It also seems like the bigger the window is, the more jumpy it gets.
Is there something in my code that's causing it to not have smooth transitions? Or am I missing something with the TweenMax implimentation? 

Your help is very appreciated.

### Update/Answer

Initially my code read as follows:

```
/* BEFORE UPDATE */
TweenMax.to($('.slide-holder'), speed, { 
            left: "-=" + xTo, 
            top: "-=" + yTo,
            overwrite: "all"
          });
```

TahirAhmed suggested changing it from `left` and `top` to `x` and `y`. Now my code looks like this and is much smoother:

```
/* AFTER UPDATE */
TweenMax.to($('.slide-holder'), speed, { 
            x: "-=" + xTo, 
            y: "-=" + yTo,
            overwrite: "all"
          });
```

Comment: Not sure what issue is with result at codepen?

Comment: The transition between slides isn't the smoothest. It seems jumpy. I'm looking at it in Chrome and Firefox. Both are having similar results.

Comment: Transition between slides appears "smooth", here, at chromium.

Comment: What if you make if full screen? I'm having the same not quite smooth effect on my phone as well.

Comment: Are you referring to the edges of the images?

Comment: I'm referring to when you click on the arrow button to move to the next slide. The transition between slides seems rough/jumpy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129949/discussion-between-guest271314-and-trevor-nestman).

Comment: instead of animating `left` and `top`, you can try animating `x` and `y` and see if it improves your result. **[Link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)**.

Comment: @TahirAhmed That made things dramatically smoother. Thanks a ton. Please post that as an answer and I'll mark it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When animating, it is recommended to use `x` and `y` instead of `left` and `top`.

References:

- Why Moving Elements With Translate() Is Better Than Pos:abs Top/left: **[Link](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)**.
- High Performance Animations: **[Link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)**.
- CSS Triggers: **[Link](https://csstriggers.com/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Tahir's answer pretty much covered it but also try adding these codes to your tween:

```
ease: Power2.easeInOut,
force3D: false,
```

and as I've seen on almost every article about tweenmax its better practice to use .fromTo()

It is also important that you don't set css transitions to the elements you want to animate, you can just add a .set({transition: " ... "}) to those elements at the end of your tweens